# Tab layout programmatically in android

Tags: android

I need to use tab layout in which i try to access two activity classes in 2 tabs programmatically. I tried but getting error in run time. refer my code below,test activity

```
public class TestActivity extends TabActivity {
    protected static final View View = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        


        Resources ressources = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
        // Android tab
                Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, AndroidActivity.class);
                TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
                  .newTabSpec("Android")

                  .setContent(intentAndroid);

                tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid); 
        setContentView(tabHost);

    }
}
```

Android activity(activity which need to display in tab order in the name as `andriod`)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidActivity extends Activity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("This is Android tab");
        setContentView(textview);
    }
}
```

I don't know whats wrong in it. please give simple sample for `TabLayout` programmatically(without using any xml files).

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: stack trace? what that mean, im new to android

Comment: Your LogCat output of the error

Comment: gives "source not found" error when i debug before the line setContentView(tabHost);(test Activity class). i thing my code was wrong and need some modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Create a parent class to display all the other classes in tab order**

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class TestActivity extends TabActivity {
protected static final View View = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

    Resources ressources = getResources(); 
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
    // Android tab
            Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, AndroidActivity.class);
            TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
              .newTabSpec("Android")
              //add .png type images in res folder hdpi,ldpi,mdpi,xhdpi
tabSpecAndroid.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrival));//arrival is the name of png image, delete this line if u hav no images
              .setContent(intentAndroid);
            tabSpecAndroid.setIndicator("Android");
            tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);     

    //Welcome tab
            Intent intentBus = new Intent().setClass(this, Welcome.class);
            TabSpec tabSpecBus = tabHost
                    .newTabSpec("Welcome")
                    .setContent(intentBus);
            tabSpecBus.setIndicator("Welcome");
            tabHost.addTab(tabSpecBus);     
}
}
```

> **create first child class in which we want to display in tab order**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidActivity extends Activity 
{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText("This is Android tab");
    setContentView(textview);
}
}
```

> **create a second child class in which we want to display in tab order**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Welcome extends Activity
{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText("This is Welcome tab");
    setContentView(textview);
}
}
```

> **in android manifest.cml add all child classes**

```
<activity android:name=".AndroidActivity"     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Welcome" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"></activity>
</application>
```

> now run the code, thats it

Answer (score 0):

A `TabActivity` probably already includes the content. Try not calling `setContentView()` and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: is my two classes are right? if i remove setcontent view i got error like "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab indicator." in logcat

Comment: pls give me simple sample if u have programmatically. without any xml files

Comment: You have to call `setIndicator()` on the `TabSpec` object.

Comment: i use setIndicator() like tabSpecAndroid.setIndicator(getCurrentFocus()); .now it shows null pointer exception

Comment: The indicator is just a title for the tab. Pass it a `CharSequence` value, such as "Tab 1".

Comment: @user1500635 No, you would accept my answer since I gave you the correct answer. The answer you posted should really just be edited into your question and **not** be a separate answer.